# Control third party cookies from Sitecore

Tags: experience-analytics, cookies

Is there a way to control the third party cookies added into my website from Sitecore?
I need to be able to block third party cookies (for example Google Analytics and LinkedIn cookies) until the user consents , I was able to achieve this using Google Tag Manager tags and triggers rules, but I need to find a way to achieve the same behavior from Sitecore without using GTM.

Is there a way to achieve this from Sitecore only?

Comment: Why don't you stop Sitecore from rendering GTM tag before user accept cookies?

Comment: @MarekMusielak i need to stop using GTM tags at all. I want to handle the full scenario from within Sitecore. So i need to handle the scenario of preventing adding the cookies in browser before the user accepts the cookies from Sitecore without using GTM

Comment: That means that your code needs to be adapted so it never renders component which loads external javascripts (or any other code which may result in adding external cookies). There is nothing out of the box - it's specific to your implementation.

Comment: @Marek Musielak thank you for your answer.Also, is there a way to check if Sitecore internally uses any google cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be adapted so it never renders component which loads external javascripts (or any other code which may result in adding external cookies).

There is nothing out of the box - it's specific to your implementation.

Sitecore does not use internally any Google or any other 3rd party provider cookies.